# Save file in newly created folder: Runtime error method save of object _workbook failed

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am trying to:
Check a specified folder to make sure a folder with the name current year exists. If not, create it.
Copy everything from Sheet1 of the already open workbook to a newly added workbook.
Save the new workbook with a specified name and close it.

If I have the folder with the name current year, the macro works as expected.
If the folder does not exist, it doesn't close the file. It shows

> run-time error "1004 method save of object _workbook failed".

```vb
Sub Copy_Data()

Dim ThisYear As String
Dim fdObj As Object
Dim wbO As Workbook

ThisYear = Format(Date, "YYYY")

Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Temp\" & ThisYear) Then GoTo DataCopy:
fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Temp\" & ThisYear)

DataCopy:

Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy

Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

wbO.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\" & ThisYear & "\Data_New_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy"), FileFormat:=51     'Stops here

Windows("Data_New_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx").Close

End Sub
```

After suggestions, I edited the code. I encounter the same problem.
The code works if I do a step-though using F8, but shows a runtime error if I run the macro.

```vb
Sub Copy_Data()

Dim ThisYear As String
Dim fdObj As Object
Dim wbO As Workbook

ThisYear = Format(Date, "YYYY")

Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear) Then
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear)
End If

Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy

Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

wbO.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear & "\Data_New_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy"), FileFormat:=51      'Stops here

wbO.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using `GoTo` like this is generally frowned upon. Instead, use `If Not fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Temp\" & ThisYear) Then`, `fdObj.CreateFolder "C:\Temp\" & ThisYear`, `End If`.

Comment: use `wb0.close` instead of referring to the window of the file ... furthermore: it doesn't make sense to use `now()` twice - it could be different!

Comment: You have write access to `C:\Temp`?  The folder `C:\Temp\2022` exists? No file exists with that name (and is write protected)?

Comment: @FunThomas, Thank you! In fact, I am using a different folder path in the macro code that I am trying, Since the folder path was showing company name, I just chose to remove that from the folder path before posting the code here. Did not think that could cause confusion. Apologies. I will change the code and repost it.

Comment: I don't mind which exact folder you are using. You need to be sure that **(a)** the folder exists **(b)** you have write access to the folder **(c)** you either ensure that the file name is unique or that in case you have already a file with that name, you are allowed to delete it (note that you can't delete a file if it is already open).

Comment: I have posted the edited codes after suggestions. Folder path still looks a bit strange because it shows "abcd" in between. I had to hide username and the company name for compliance reasons. While doing step-through, the macro works fine, but if I run it then I get a runtime error. Could you please suggest something?

Comment: @FunThomas, If the folder does not exist, then the code creates a folder. It successfully does it. And I have a write access to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some trial and error and with some googling, I figured out that this runtime error "method save of object _workbook failed" occurs when trying to save file as xlsx. If the file format chosen is xls, then the macro works perfectly fine. But I prefer to have the file saved in xlsx format.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/solved-quot-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed-quot-1004/m-p/3249728

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-you-run-a-visual-basic-for-applications-macro-in-excel-method-saveas-of-object-worksheet-failed-376fcbb2-9941-f34d-1aba-ca602903245f

Since my macro creates the folder if it does not exist, and also saves the file with specified name, I just chose to skip that error message using `On Error Resume Next` The macro works as expected now. Below is the code that I used.

```
Sub Copy_Data()

Dim ThisYear As String
Dim fdObj As Object
Dim wbO As Workbook

ThisYear = Format(Date, "YYYY")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear) Then
fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear)
End If

Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy

Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

On Error Resume Next

wbO.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\abcd\OneDrive - abcd\Desktop\Temp\" & ThisYear & "\Data_New_" & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy"), FileFormat:=51

wbO.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```